# Corner missing on rectangle

Tags: python, pygame

While working on my game, I noticed that when rendering rectangles, sometimes the bottom-right corners are just cut off by one pixel.

[Notice the missing pixels on the gray boxes.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JomQB.png)

I have a Box class that updates every frame:

```
class Box:
    def __init__(self, x, y, width, height):
        self.rectbox = pyg.Rect(x, y, width, height)
    def update(self):
        pyg.draw.rect(screen, light_gray, self.rectbox) # Main box
        pyg.draw.rect(screen, black, self.rectbox, 2) # Box outline
    def getRect(self):
        return self.rectbox
```

Is this my mistake or just how pygame renders rectangles?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems to be just when drawing rectangles with an outline.
A simple fix is to draw a solid rectangle black and a slightly smaller rectangle light_gray on top of it

```
class Box:
    def __init__(self, x, y, width, height, w):
        self.rectbox_outline = pyg.Rect(x, y, width, height) 
        self.rectbox_main = pyg.Rect(x+w//2,y+w//2,width-w,height-w)
    def update(self):
        pyg.draw.rect(screen, black, self.rectbox_outline) # Box outline
        pyg.draw.rect(screen, light_gray, self.rectbox_main) # Main box
    def getRect(self):
        return self.rectbox
```

Comment: Thanks! This worked with a bit of tweaking to `self.rectbox_outline` so that the line thickness would be the same as before.

Comment: No problem. make -2 in `pyg.Rect(x+1,y+1,width-2,height-2)` a variable and make +1 the variable/2 to make it easy